# Prove that if $m$ divide $n$ then $x^{p^{m-1}}-1$ divide $x^{p^{n-1}}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I have been trying for several days to prove the equality of the title, but without any positive results. I know I have to first prove that if m divides n (it has to be multiple of m) then $p^{m}-1$ divide $p^{n}-1$.

That is the one that I have been able to demonstrate knowing that there is a quotient for this division that has zero rest and is the following: $\sum_{i=1}^{\alpha}(p^{(\alpha-i)\times m})$.

Someone could help me relate it to the title and get the proof.

Thanks.

Comment: If $a\mid b$ then $(x^a-1)\mid(x^b-1)$ as polynomials.

Comment: And thus it need no $m\mid n$, just $m\leq n$.

Comment: Did you intend to write $\, p^{\large m-1}$ divides $\,p^{\large n-1}\ $? $ $  If so please correct the question. If not please explain why you think you need to first prove that.

Comment: It´s correct what i wrote in the post. I think that both proves same.

Comment: Both are not the same. To find $gcd(x^{p^m-1}-1,x^{p^n-1}-1)$ we can use that $gcd(u^a-1,u^b-1) = u^{gcd(a,b)}-1$ two times, in two different rings. Is it true in every ring $R$ that for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1},u \in R$ then as ideals $(u^a-1,u^b-1) = (u^{gcd(a,b)}-1)$ ?

Comment: @Str0nger If differs from the title so maybe the title is not what you intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $n=mk$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.  Now we have
$$p^n-1=(p^m)^k-1=(p^m-1)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(p^m)^j$$
This is an application of the factorization identity
$$(x^n-1)=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+1)$$
which you should definitely memorize.